# Facebook Graph API v2.0 deprecation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've received this e-mail from facebook:

> Souts Pay has been making recent API calls to Graph API v2.0, which
>   will reach the end of the 2-year deprecation window on Monday, August
>   8, 2016. Please migrate all calls to v2.1 or higher in order to avoid
>   potential broken experiences.
>
> We recommend using our new Graph API Upgrade Tool to see which of your
>   calls are affected by this change as well as any replacement calls in
>   newer versions. You can also use our changelog to see the full list of
>   changes.

But when I click at [Graph API Upgrade Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/900643053338019) I got this message:

> Your app hasn't made enough calls to the Graph API to show any info,
>   or there are no changes for the methods you selected between v2.5 and
>   v2.6

So should I worry about this facebook issue? If yes, how can I make this upgrade?

Comment: may be related to this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1634445133540643/

Comment: @luschn thanks a lot! It explains the issue.

Comment: Hi I checked this link. And verified all details.
I am having v2.0 but in the API upgrade tool, when I select versions to migrate, I am getting following message

"Your app hasn't made enough calls to the Graph API to show any info, or there are no changes for the methods you selected between v2.0 and v2.7"

Means I don't have to worry about this warning for my app?

Comment: I am using facebook login for my site ... I received warning mail, when   I try to upgrade using I got message "Your app has no changes for the methods you selected between v2.6 and v2.12"

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook API is always changing, then if you received this message, you just need to use the API version in your URL:

Eg:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me

If you don't specify the version

https://graph.facebook.com/me

It always will use the oldest version possible, actually is v2.6

Some APIs can be deprecated, but login function is working fine, stay tuned for recent changes here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/